# Centos 7 install MySQL5..5

Tags: mysql-5.5, centos

Install MySQL5.5 in CentOS7 by following instructions on this page: [A Quick Guide to Using the MySQL Yum Repository](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/)

After that start the service: `service mysqld start`

This returns the error:

`Job for mysqld.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Below is the mysqld log file:

```
[root@iZu1a81d1qsZ log]# vi mysqld.log
160513 00:11:16 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from     /var/lib/mysql
160513  0:11:16 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.49) starting as process 15341 ...
160513  0:11:16 [ERROR] An old style --language value with language specific part detected: /usr/share/mysql/
160513  0:11:16 [ERROR] Use --lc-messages-dir without language specific part instead.
160513  0:11:16 [ERROR] Can't read from messagefile '/usr/share/mysql/errmsg.sys'
160513  0:11:16 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Unknown error 1146
160513  0:11:16 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
160513  0:11:16 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160513  0:11:16 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160513  0:11:16 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160513  0:11:16 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160513  0:11:16 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160513  0:11:16 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160513  0:11:16 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160513  0:11:16  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160513  0:11:17 InnoDB: 5.5.49 started; log sequence number 1595675
160513  0:11:17 [ERROR] Aborting

160513  0:11:17  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160513  0:11:18  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number     1595675
160513  0:11:18 [Note]
160513 00:11:18 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

My question is: what causes this? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem you are hitting is the one on line 8:

`160513  0:11:16 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.`

You can run the command `mysql_upgrade` to create the missing table.